# Set the width of a view to 50% of its container in the nib

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I am creating a view with four table views in it. I want each table view to take 50% of the height and width of the containing view and to auto-resize when the window is resized.

I have been unable to find a way to do this thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use autolayout in storyboard. Resizing and stuff like that becomes very easy that way. Basically you want to set constraints for each tableview to the edges which they are touching and their neighboring tableviews (distance: 0). Furthermore you have to set constraints for equal width and equal heights.

Comment: I was just starting to figure that out. Thanks!